# LINQ where query on collection of different derived classes

Tags: linq

I have a collection of different objects that derive from the same parent.

How can I extract objects of a particular type from a collection containing mixed types

e.g.

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
public class C : A {}
```

The collection will contain objects of type B and C

I'm halfway there just need help filling in the '[]' bit

```
var x = from xTypes in xCollection where '[type of object is type B]' select xTypes;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `OfType<T>` extension method rather than LINQ query syntax for this:

```
var x = xCollection.OfType<B>();
```

This will give you back an `IEnumerable<B>`. If you do want to use the LINQ query syntax, you'd have to do this:

```
var x = from obj in xCollection where obj is B select (B)obj;
```

Comment: I like the extension method. Much cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = from xTypes in xCollection 
        where xTypes is B 
        select xTypes;
```

or if you want exactly this type and not any derived types:

```
var x = from xTypes in xCollection 
        where xTypes.GetType() == typeof(B) 
        select xTypes;
```